# What does :constant mean in ARM and what does it mean specifically in VLDn's address register?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I am learning neon and found a line of code as the following:

```
DATA            .req r0  
vld1.16         {d16, d17, d18, d19}, [DATA, :128]!
```

I can not find any information about what the :128 means. In RealView Compilation Tools® Version 3.1 Assembler Guide, immediate value in vldn's address register is not defined,
even if :128 means #128. What is the difference between :128 and #128? What does :128 mean exactly in this instruction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembler syntax for that instruction according to the [ARM Architecture Reference Manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Finfocenter.arm.com%2Fhelp%2Ftopic%2Fcom.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference%2F&ei=-58OUdHjHKnBiwKkjYHoBA&usg=AFQjCNHPDMXGQsHlDWpoabdb-FP0GnS89A&sig2=E4_gZC-e6w5DD8LjZI9jlQ&bvm=bv.41867550,d.cGE) is:

```
VLD1<c><q>.<size> <list>, [<Rn>{@<align>}]!
```

So it looks like your `:128` means `@128` from that context.

> **`<align>`** The alignment. It can be one of:
>
> ...
>
> **`128`** 16-byte alignment, available only if **`<list>`** contains two or four registers.

Comment: true, reason for the change @ -> : is gnu asm recognizes @ as a comment start.

Comment: That would make sense, yup.